# Remount Android file system through java

Tags: android, android-source

I need to remount android file system as read write instead of read only. I know how to do it through command prompt and also how to go about it for application development.

But I am into tweaking the android source code and there if I use

```
Process proc=Runtime.getRuntime.exec("su");
```

it doesnot work. Therefore I need to use `android.os.process` object for the same and I am stuck here can anybody help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try this code to get superuser access (you'll need a **rooted phone** with superuser installed):

   ```
   try {
       // Perform su to get root privledges
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

       DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

       os.writeBytes("<..... here you may write commands ....>\n");

       // Close the terminal
       os.writeBytes("exit\n");
       os.flush();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       toastMessage("not root");
   }
   ```
2. Once you have superuser access, you may start `adbd` listening on some TCP port using:

   ```
   setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
   adbd &
   setprop service.adb.tcp.port -1
   ```
3. Open a TCP connection to the selected port and issue `remount` command.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's difficult to understand what are you going to do. But if you're tweaking android sources (aosp) then it's will be easier for you to modify `init.rc` (which is under system/core/rootdir) file to get system image rw. If you want to change the state during the runtime you need to create your own native application (for instance, look into the run-as command), change inside it the uid of the process, make it as suid,  embed it into the sources, and call it from your application.

Comment: I need to build a customized rom. I don't have to change init.rc coz it will be read write all the time. For implementing a certain use case I want to mount it as read write in PackageServiceManager.java and then revert to read only. Actually i need to edit the apks which are there in system/app directory. Hence for that I need read write.

Comment: Then, follow my second part of the answer. Create your in the android source and call this app.